# how to get the actor bounds after rotation and drag

Tags: box2d, libgdx, actor

I am unable to get the exact bounds of an actor after some sequential step like drag and drooping it to some point and then rotate it around its origin.

I have to do this...
Mirrors(taken as actor) have to dragged into the path of the light and rotate to change the direction of reflection.

For reflection with light i need exact hit point of the actor(mirror).

For drag and drop i just used draglistner on it.
and for rotation actor.rotate(angle);

the big problem comes in when I rotate the actor, and then try to drag it: At 30 degrees rotation, drag acts fine. But when rotate an angle greater then 30 then behavior is abnormal.

Comment: What is this abnormal behavior? Did you set the origin of your actor to its middle? For the intersection point between mirror and light i think you have to create a polygon with the size of your mirror. You can rotate polygons and then you can check intersections between the light-line and the lines of your polygon.

Comment: @Springrbua already did the same, anyway thanx for the reply.

Comment: And what is exactly your problem at the moment?